# Windows Server 2008 Incoming connections limit

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vpn

I have stup Incomming Connection on Windows 2008 Server. I set it up from network adapters window.

The problem is that I can connect only 5 users at a time.

Where can I increase the number of concurent users connected through VPN Channel?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply buy more CALs from Microsoft.